# Faster reaction rate with increased surface area

Tags: geometry, area

If the largest dimension of a CaCO3 tablet that can be packaged economically is 10 mm (meaning a radius can be a maximum of 5 mm). What would be the best shape for the shape of the tablet? By best, I simply want to know which tablet shape would allow for the greatest surface area (and hence, react the fastest with HCl). I'm thinking a torus might be the best option, is there something better?

**EDIT:** What would be the best option (given the restrictions on the dimensions) if I had to choose between a cube, pyramid, sphere, cylinder or torus?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Surely there are physic restrictions to the shape of the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Something really prickly will have lots of surface area, as will powders and shapes like steel wool.  These are all used to carry catalysts in industrial processes for this reason.

Comment: Ok, what would be the best option (given the restrictions) if I had to choose between a cube, pyramid, sphere, cylinder or torus?

Comment: @turbo:  I would guess the torus because it gets the added area around the hole, but wouldn't be sure without doing the computation.  The sphere would be second best as you get a curvy surface above the flat surfaces of all the others.  Of course that takes the most $CaCO_3$.  If you want to dissolve the $CaCO_3$ as quickly as possible you want the thinnest shape you can get